# Using crow's feet notation in data modelling in enterprise architect

Tags: data-modeling, enterprise-architect, multiplicity

I am only able to use connectors in enterprise architect with traditional 0..* style multiplicity rather than crow's feet connectors. I've tried using different drawing styles and still cannot work out how to change the connectors. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a way to use the crow's foot notation. Actually it's pretty simple. Here's how to do it:

1. Right-click data-diagram and select properties (you can do it in the working area directly or through browsing the Project Browser).
2. Navigate to the Connectors tab.
3. On the right side you'll see a small section labeled "Connector Notation", there you select "Information Engineering" and that's it!

Comment: Great!  Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Been looking through all the options for this. Cheers.

Comment: I just downloaded the trial (version 10) and not familiar with it... Right click where... I am not seeing anything of "Data-Diagram", nor other steps subsequent.  I do have a project, connected to data source, downloaded the table structures and put 3 on the diagram.  Even created connector between tables and set source/target and respective columns.  Hopefully something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: I think they may have changed the location a few times. On 14.1, you can get the full diagram properties by double clicking in an empty area of the diagram, or by selecting the diagram in the Project Browser and selecting Edit->Properties from the Layout Ribbon tab. In there, select the Connectors node from the left hand side of the dialog, and change the dropdown on Connector Notation to Information Engineering.